# Some elements in website have hover properties and are clickable but not the Div provided by Chrome's "inspect" option. Selenium, Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a **Python** script that gets information about flyers on the site "*doveconviene.it*", this site has some flyers (not every flyer, see next paragraph) with clickable products that gives the product name and price inside a modal div that appers when you click on the product, this modal is empty until you click on a product of the flyer, so, to retrieve the informations i need, i have to click on the product.

To replicate what i'm saying:

1. Go to "doveconviene.it", select a **supermarket flyer** with products that become darker when you pass the mouse (try with Lidl, Eurospin, MD, Penny flyer or other **supermarket flyers**).
2. Click on a product.
3. A modal window will appear with the product image, name and price.

I'm trying to use **Selenium** in **Python** to scroll through each product in the flyer, click on it, retrieve the product name and price from the modal div and then move to the next product div in the same page to do the same.

The **problem** is that, using Chrome, when right-click and inspect the element of a product, the div returned is not clickable so i can't automate clicks on those elements to retrive the informations i need.

Every product of the flyer has the following HTML structure:

```
<div class = "css-0 e5l4rtr2">

  <div class = "css-XXXXX e5l4rtr0">
    <div role = "button">
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class = "css-XXXXX e5l4rtr1">  <- Div selected by Chrome's 'inspect' option
  </div>  

</div>
```

This is what i did to get the flyer page i'm working on:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless=new')  # Run Chrome in headless mode

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.doveconviene.it/discount/penny/volantino/ultime-offerte-penny?flyerId=1117478&flyerPage=1")
driver.maximize_window()
```

To select the div provided by Chrome's 'inspect' option related to a product, i'm using the following istructions:

```
productDiv = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'e5l4rtr1')]")))

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(productDiv))

productDiv.click()
```

Latter instruction gives me the following error, so this div is not clickable (isn't it?):

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div x="29.55555555555556" y="423.11111111111103" width="276.44444444444446" height="352.0000000000001" class="css-ghw7y6 e5l4rtr1"></div> is not clickable at point (1331, 666).

I've tried without the second instruction but without success.

I've also tried ***.click()*** on the other div that has ***role = button*** attribute, again without success.

**Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Which element of the page needs be clicked to open the modal window?**

Comment: is that all your code? - in particular, Did you accept the cookie message?  (it has a good id too = 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler' ) Every time you launch selenium it creates a new chrome user profile for your run - it's like your visiting your site for the first time every time. If you turn off headless and watch it run you should notice that cookie message, or if you manually want to follow it use an icognito session.

Comment: No, the problem was, in fact, the accept cookie message. 
I don't know why, but even using headless mode, cookie message still pops up, why does this happen? Shoud it not apperar using "options.add_argument('--headless=new')"?

P.S. Thank you so much for the reply below, that trick is so usefull and now i understand how to use XPath expressions in chrome's console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you see is caused by the 'privacy settings' (accept cookies) alert which is displayed when you enter the website for the 1st time (from a new user session).

You can disable the headless mode to see that alert.

To resolve this, you can either enter the website > [add cookie](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/cookies/) (in your case cookie name is OptanonConsent) > refresh the page

Or you can handle it explicitly via Selenium:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
short_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)

driver.get("https://www.doveconviene.it/discount/penny/volantino/ultime-offerte-penny?flyerId=1117478&flyerPage=1")
driver.maximize_window()

# handle cookies modal
try:
    el = short_wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")))
    if el.is_displayed():
        el.click()
except TimeoutException:
    pass
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")))

# parsing logic goes here
# parsing logic goes here
# parsing logic goes here
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'e5l4rtr1')]")))
products = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'e5l4rtr1')]")
for product in products:
    product.click()

    name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class, 'e6sviiv0')]"))).text
    price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'e10wf1jb0')]"))).text

    print(f"Collected {name} with price {price}")
```

Also, I'd recommend you to pay attention to locators, classes like 'e5l4rtr1' can by dynamic (i.e. generated by the frontend framework).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have python installed here but it looks like you can activate the click by using javascript.

You were close when you tried `\\div[@role='button']` - that click works from the devtools console.

To get you started - run this in python :

```py
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@name='username'])[3]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
```

Why `[3]` i hear you ask?
I'm in lidl in [this](https://www.doveconviene.it/discount/lidl/volantino/ultime-offerte-lidl?flyerId=1118149&flyerPage=3&utm_medium=rsv&origin_retailer_id=31&flyerGibId=659fd13b-e030-4685-b91b-000a43be90da) flyer.
There are 22 hits for for the neat `@role=button`.

You can only tell selenium 1 element to click - the `[3]` is the 3rd element that matches the xpath.

This is how my devtools & webpage look with the match:
[image: web page with item highlighted]

A really good trick here: To quickly test which item to click, use the devtools console.

Select the highlighted line (or any line) in the element viewer and you'll notice chrome adds `== $0` to the end. Chrome has assigned that element to a variable called `$0`.

Go to the console and type `$0.click()`. That will the activate the action i think you wanted:
[image: click with console]

Finally -  putting all this together - If you want to click through all the items, you will need to iterate all items on the page - do this with `find_elements_by_xpath` (note it's element*s* - returns an array of items). Then you can iterate through those to do you actions.

More examples of how to execute a selenium click with JS via python [here](https://dzone.com/articles/perform-actions-using-javascript-in-python-seleniu).